# What does (number) in the YouTube tab mean?

Tags: youtube

A number is starting to appear in YouTube Tab title recently like in the image (686) What does it mean? It's also increasing day by day.

[image: YouTube Tab Title]

Comment: I don't see it. Do you have any suspicious add-on?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I tried disabling my extensions. But it's still there. I've seen in Quora.com that this is also appearing for others.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-does-100-in-the-YouTube-tab-mean

Comment: @AtanuCSE That link has no answers, so not terribly helpful

Comment: @EricF Uhu!! I was just showing that this is appearing to others too.  If that link contained any answer I would have deleted the question already...

Comment: Does this number appear in other browsers?

Comment: I see a (22) on a video that has 20 Likes and 0 dislikes.  There goes my theory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### A number is starting to appear in YouTube Tab title - what does it mean?

> It's apparently yet another unannounced change made by Google/ YouTube and the numbers in the brackets in the browsers tab apparently indicate how many comments/ posts you currently have on YouTube which you have not yet read/ checked...

Source [There is a number next to my YouTube tab that keeps appearing](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/-NlCunvrbqw)

---

#### So how can I remove it?

> 1. sign in to your YouTube account
> 2. click on the bell icon (top right side in YouTube)
> 3. click on the gear icon
> 4. deactivate "desktop notifications"

Source [There is a number next to my YouTube tab that keeps appearing](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/-NlCunvrbqw)

Comment: I do not believe this is true though.  I dont think it indicates unread messages. This is because different youtube video tabs will have drastically different numbers. I get a (12) on one tab and a (343) in another.  And I NEVER read my youtube messages so I know the numbers have got to be ginormous.

Comment: I already have desktop notifications disabled and it's still showing up. I think the reason this "works" is that clicking the bell marks all your notifications as read, rather than actually disabling the feature.

Answer (score 5):

It's the amount of unread notifications you have.

In the upper right on Youtube you have a notification icon:

[image: notification icon]

When you click it, the number will disappear.

Comment: Or install a Chrome add-on to get rid of this (because it is an annoying issue when bookmarking to the bookmark bar): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-youtube-tab-number/mbdhdllcfaijbnebmfnglclcgfopejop