# Why there is no (number) in the YouTube tab anymore?

Tags: youtube

Usually, when you have (number) on a YouTube tab, that means you have unread notifications. Now, the number tab is Removed. Why did they remove the number tab in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying was an issue before. I have found this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105628/what-does-number-in-the-youtube-tab-mean/105629) as well. In my opinion, google removed this cause people did not like this and it was confusing to some people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: but that means that you have notifications